# Cheerio can't find IMG src

Tags: javascript, express, cheerio, scraper

My cheerio code doesn't seem to be working. I'm trying to get the src from the `<img>` tag found inside of the `imgWrap` div at the given link.

I've tried rewriting `.imgWrap` as `.imgWrap img` and removing the `find` but that didn't work either...

However, if i do `$(element).children()` or `$(element).html()` I see the results I expect to...

```
request.get('http://www.bk.com/menu/burgers', function(error, response, body) {
   const $ = cheerio.load(body);

   let menu = $('.imgWrap').each(function(i, element) {
      let thing = $(element).find('img').attr('src');
      console.log(thing);
   });
})
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Turns out this specific website uses lazy-loading to load their images, so the view source upon inspecting is actually different than the information received in the get request.

the get request does not have an `src` associated with the `img` element, but rather a `data-cfsrc` which is holding the same information as the `src` in the view source.

so, the line should actually be this:

```
let thing = $(element).find('img').attr('data-cfsrc');
```

Thanks big time to @rlemon for the help in troubleshooting this!

Comment: im trying to use this and it dives me undefined, this is my result when i put in "src" instead of data-cfsrc, data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAIAAAAAAAP///yH5BAEAAAAALAAAAAABAAEAAAIBRAA7